# Passing parameters to button click methods within the SAME windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently programming Hangman in C# using windows form and I've got a fair way through it. I'm using an array to store the words that can be guessed - a bit limited I know, but I don't know much about databases. I use a random number generator to search through the array to select a word.

Is there a way to pass parameters to different methods within the SAME windows form?? So far, when I create a parameter inside a button click method the design form disappears and says I cant edit it. I have different methods set up which consist of button clicks, and I would need to send each method the selected word to check whether it had any of those specific letters in it.
Any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass extra parameters to click handlers. Just add a private field to form which will contain selected word and every method in the form will have access to it.